# Is is safe to wash your engine bay?

Tags: detailing

Civic couPe vti 1999.

I am thinking about washing my engine bay with water.

So long as I remove the battery and leave car to dry for a week will I be safe from any electrical problems?

Are there other parts I should isolate?

Do people do this successfully or do they mess up?

Comment: If you can’t keep up with a few leaves then I doubt your engine bay cleaning abilities... see https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/80233/10976

Answer (score 2):

Perfectly safe - the engine bay is not sealed, so it gets sprayed with water every time you go through a deep puddle.

Obviously don't immerse the electrical bits in water, but wiping them over will be fine.

Caveat though - there is no point! Most of the filth in an engine bay is grease or oil, which water won't shift. You'd be better off with a proper degreaser.

Comment: My car has a very good under engine cover protection so it keeps puddle moisture out and I don’t drive through rivers.

Answer (score 0):

Depends: If one uses a power washer and isn't cautious he can create quite a damage.
While all electrical contacts are quite well isolated (the seals won't get better over time, so a 21 year old car hasn't certainly pristine seals) the high pressure jet of a power washer can enter the isolated zones (or bearings) and cause problems.

Washing with a proper degreaser, without power washer, should be fine